# Does postblit constructor differ only by source from copy constructor?

Tags: c++, d, copy-constructor

If I understand correctly postblit constructor in D starts from bitwise copy (always), then there is user-defined body of it.

But when I look at the body of postblit constructor it is very similar to C++ copy constructor, the only difference is in C++ the source is some object, when in D is `this` (itself).

Am I correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eh, close. I think you have a pretty good handle on it, but to spell it out:

`a = b;` (iff a and b are both the same type, a struct) translates into:

```
memcpy(&a, &b, b.sizeof); // bitwise copy
a.__postblit(); // call the postblit on the destination only (iff this(this) is defined on the type!)
```

So you don't have to explicitly assign any variables in the postblit (they are all copied automatically) and also cannot use it to implement move semantics (you don't have access to the source).

The place I most often use the postblit is when the struct is a pointer to another object, so I can increase the refcount:

```
struct S {
    SomeObject* wrapped;
    this(this) { if(wrapped) wrapped.addReference(); }
    ~this() { if(wrapped) wrapped.releaseReference(); }
}
```

This only works with references since otherwise you'd be incrementing a copy of the variable!

You *can* (but shouldn't) also use it to perform deep copies:

```
struct S {
   string content;
   this(this) { content = content.idup; }
}
```

But that's actually a bad idea since struct assignment is supposed to be universally cheap in D and deep copies aren't cheap. There's also generally no need anyway, since the garbage collector handles cases like double free where you might want this in C++.

The other case where I use it a lot in D is actually to disable it:

```
struct S {
   @disable this(this);
}
S a, b;
a = b; // compile error, b is not copyable
```

That's different than just not implementing a postblit at all, which leaves you with the automatic implementation of memcpy. This makes assignment an outright compile error, which you can use to funnel the user toward another method, for move semantics for example:

```
struct S {
   int* cool;
   @disable this(this);
   S release() { auto n = cool; cool = null; return S(cool); }
}
```

Since a=b is prohibited, we can now force the user to use the .release method when they want to reassign it which does our moving.

Comment: Thank you very much. However your comment about deep copy puzzled me. AFAIK D by default makes a shallow copy, so when I need a deep copy how do I implement it? Also I don't understand what deep copy has to do with GC -- it is for separating data, not for any kind of memory optimization.

Comment: If you need a deep copy, you should make a method to do it (personally, like to name it `clone`, but that's arbitrary preference). Just like with the `release` thing, you could also choose to disable the postblit to force users to call your clone method instead. This seems like extra steps, but the idea is to keep generic algorithms from exploding in complexity. Consider calling a sort algorithm or something that does a lot of swapping with the a=b operator, assuming it to be a fast bitwise copy. If that assumption was wrong, your sort may end up being way way slower since it over-copies.

Comment: re the gc, what I mean there is just that in C++ you might copy something as a way to take ownership, to ensure it doesn't get freed while you're still using it. That particular class of copies is unnecessary here because the GC will never free something if *anybody* still holds a reference. Moreover, the `immutable` qualifier can help eliminate copies too because they guarantee nobody will ever change that data. strings in D are immutable refs so there's never a need to copy them for this reason either. If you need a separate data thing for private changes though, of course, you still copy.